# Busca em Recorte OAB

Tags: php, ajax, libcurl

Existem varios programas juridicos ( para advogados) que fazem a leitura do recorte da OAB, a evolução do processo, automaticamente, trazendo para ele essas mudanças diariamente.

A idéia é colocar dentro de um mini sistema de processos que temos dentro do escritório, sem ter a necessidade de entrar toda vez no portal para consultar. Fazer pelos dados de Login do Advogado (OAB e UF) ele puxar nesse cURL os dados pro dia.

Ele faria a consulta por cURL em portais da OAB, por estado, dos processos que aquele advogado tem.

Alguem já fez ou tem idéia de como posso buscar estes dados, dado o fato dele entrar com o numero do processo?

Comment: Que dados? Onde estão, como são formatados? O que vc já tentou? Tem alguma dúvida *específica* sobre esse processo de leitura? Lembre-se, por favor, que esse site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, por favor leia a [help] e, principalmente, [ask]. :)

Comment: a dúvida seria realmente esta, qual a melhor forma para obter estes dados vindo de outro site, sendo que eu estaria enviando uma array para automaticamente preencher os campos no portal da OAB ( no caso a inscrição da OAB e o UF do advogado). Não fiz testes ainda, pois não tenho um caminho a seguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base na [URL](http://www.trt9.jus.br/internet_base/processooabadvsel.do) que você passou no comentário .. Montei isto, mas aviso logo: O sistema deles ocasionalmente exibe o recaptcha do Google , e com isso eu quero dizer que depois que eles detectaram que eu estava usando um bot para fazer as consultas, todas elas após vieram com o captcha. Dito isto, segue o código ao qual eu usava usando a biblioteca cURL do Sean Huber que se encontra disponível [aqui](http://github.com/shuber/curl).

```
<?php

require_once 'lib'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'curl.php';
require_once 'lib'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'curl_response.php';

$cookie = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."oab.txt";
$url = "http://www.trt9.jus.br/internet_base/processooabadvsel.do";
$oab = "123456";
$uf = "PR";
$post = "lookupCorrentePlc=&modoPlc=consultaPlc&indExcDetPlc=&ordenacaoPlc=&evento=F9-Pesquisar&oabAdv_Arg=".$oab."&ufOabAdv_Arg=".$uf;

// instancia a classe
$curl = new Curl;

// parâmetros
$curl->cookie_file = $cookie;
$curl->options['AUTOREFERER'] = true;

// consulta
$pegaCookie = $curl->get($url);

// parâmetros
$curl->cookie_file = $cookie;
$curl->options['AUTOREFERER'] = true;
$curl->referer = $url;
$pegaCookie = $curl->get($url, $post);

// verifica se não achou nada
$preg = preg_match("/Nenhum registro encontrado/i", $pegaCookie->body);
$recaptcha = preg_match("/g-recaptcha/i", $pegaCookie->body);

if($preg > 0) {
    $resultado = "Nenhum registro encontrado";
} else {
    if($recaptcha > 0) {
        $resultado = "Esbarrou no recaptcha";
    } else {
        $resultado = "Encontrou alguma coisa";
    }
}

echo $resultado;
```

Não sei se você já viu este [Recorte Digital](http://www.recortedigital.oabdf.org.br/), mas nele não tive problema em fazer as requisições cURL.

Comment: Muito bom este esquema. A idéia é colocar dentro de um mini sistema de processos que temos dentro do escritório, sem ter a necessidade de entrar toda vez no portal para consultar. Fazer pelos dados de Login do Advogado (OAB e UF) ele puxar nesse cURL os dados pro dia.

Comment: Quer uma dica? Neste segundo link que eu coloquei na publicação tem um esquema que o advogado cadastra e todo dia chega no email o resumo , kk ... Meu primo é advogado e me mostrou funcionando.

Comment: neste exemplo que tu escreveu acima, porque ele esta direcionando para a pagina do cURL?

Comment: @LeandroGuilherme ele está imprimindo o conteúdo que tem na página , se você quiser tratar o conteúdo que há na página , com a última variável que há disponível no código $resultado você consegue fazer o que for necessário..

Comment: Editei a resposta. Para considerações como "espero ter ajudado" ou "é só perguntar novamente caso tenha alguma dúvida" use os comentários.

Answer (score 0):

Eu procurei sobre o que é este Recorte OAB e descobri que é um painel para um advogado, certo?

Sendo, é possível fazer conexão e explorar tudo que houver dentro deste painel com cURL.

Para isto são necessários dados de login válidos para entrar no site e fazer este tratamento criando sua própria ferramenta para tal fato, isto, claro se não for crime, uma vez que você está entrando numa colmeia de abelhas, rsrs

Vou deixar aqui um exemplo simples e prático do uso do cURL:

```
<?php
// cria uma nova instância
$ch = curl_init();

// configura as opções que o cURL espera ..
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/"); // url para acesso
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // não retornar o cabeçalho

// executa a requisição
curl_exec($ch);

// fecha a conexão
curl_close($ch);
```

Neste exemplo ele irá imprimir o site do google na sua página.

Comment: é necessário apenas a oab e a data para ter acesso, veja: http://www.trt9.jus.br/internet_base/processooabadvsel.do